# How to get every result value in lower case?

Tags: xslt

How to get result value in lower or upper case.
Below line will generate  result, I want every result in lower or upper case.

```
<xsl:value-of select="Value" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using xslt-1.0:

```
<xsl:variable name="smallcase" select="'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'" />
<xsl:variable name="uppercase" select="'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'" />

<xsl:value-of select="translate(Value, $uppercase, $smallcase)" />
```

reverse $uppercase and $smallcase if you want the other way around.

Using xslt-2.0

```
<xsl:value-of select="lower-case(Value)" />
```

Comment: Note that the XSLT 1.0 solution is narrowly ethno-centric. There are many more lower-case characters than that: characters with diacritics, Russian, Greek... Even in English you may encounter rôle, résumé, Beyoncé...

Comment: Michael, Do u have any suggestion to achieve this in XSLT 1.0 ?

Comment: @Sam I don't know of another way to do this other than what Joel suggested. You just need to be aware of the limitation and expand the alphabet as necessary for your needs.